# Possible Null Reference Exception using "as" operator

Tags: c#, resharper, nullreferenceexception

In the following code:

```
MyObject objInstance;

private void someEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (sender == objInstance && (sender as MyObject).SomeBoolProperty)
        // Do Something
}
```

Resharper is warning that `sender as MyObject` may be a possible NullReferenceException.  Is that possible given this code?  I'm assuming that if `sender == objInstance` that `(sender as MyObject)` won't return null, but this wouldn't be the first time a Resharper message has informed me of a C# behavior/feature I was unaware of.

Comment: Since you've established their equality, why not just use `objInstance` rather than `(sender as MyObject)`?

Comment: Already made that change, since the `if` body is using `objInstance` and I don't like those squiggly lines.  I was more interested in what was causing them.

Comment: If objInstance is null, `sender == objInstance` could return true, even though it's null. This would cause the next part of the conditional statement to throw a NullReferenceException.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code can definitely cause a `NullReferenceException` to be thrown.  Consider the case where `objInstance` and `sender` have the value `null`.  In that case `sender == objInstance` will be `true` because `null == null` and hence the `sender as MyObject` will also return `null` and the code will throw on the property access

The best way to write that code would be

```
var senderObj = sender as MyObject;
if (senderObj != null && 
    senderObj == objInstance && 
    senderObj.SomeBoolProperty) { 
  // Do something
}
```

Unfortunately I don't believe there is a way to significantly simplify this code.  There are 3 specific unrelated conditions you are attempting to express.  Hence they must all be tested for

Comment: Quite true. Missed that nuance.

Comment: Can a sender by null, though? I suppose it could if the reference is set to null after the event is raised? - actually, i guess there is no guarantee that sender is actually the sender. I've sent sender as null to events before myself...

Comment: @Michael it can definitely be `null`. The event pattern just uses delegates and you can pass `null` to delegates just fine.  In general it won't be `null` but that doesn't mean it can't be :)

Answer (score 6):

When you use [as](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cscsdfbt.aspx), `null` is returned if the object couldn't be converted (in this case, to `MyObject`). Therefore, your line `(sender as MyObject)` has the potential to be null.

Comment: True, but my question was about this specific case, where we know `sender` is equal to a specific instance of `MyObject` before the `as` operation

Comment: @HarrisonPaine - But we don't know `sender` is equal to the specific instance because `sender` could be null and so could `objInstance` thus not short-circuiting the `if` check.  The `NullReferenceException` will then be thrown when `SomeBoolProperty` is accessed.

Comment: Also, resharper is going to give you that error because theoretically you could assign that event handler to some other element that isnt going to be sending a `MyObject` as the sender. So it's a valid message, but it's up to you whether or not you want to ignore it. Your first if condition could be false.

Answer (score 3):

In this case you know that sender is really a `MyObject`. So use a simple cast instead of `as`:

```
if (sender == objInstance && ((MyObject)sender).SomeBoolProperty)
```

Or, even better:

```
if (sender == objInstance && objInstance.SomeBoolProperty)
```

Answer (score 2):

The as operator returns null if your cast is not valid. If the Event sender is not of MyObject, (sender as MyObject) == null.

If objInstance is guaranteed to not be null, then your statement will never throw a NullReferenceException. However, it may throw if objInstance is null.

Since you can determine sender == objInstance, just operate on objInstance rather than casting sender, after verifying objInstance != null.

Answer (score 1):

This is because R# isn't always the smartest. Also, you could still get a `NullReferenceException` if both `sender` and `objInstance` are `null`. Anyways, as you've established their equality, why not just use `objInstance`?

Try this instead:

```
if (sender == objInstance && objInstance.SomeBoolProperty)
```

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of the squiggly:

```
MyObject objInstance;

private void someEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var myObj = sender as MyObject;

    Debug.Assert(myObj != null);

    if (sender == objInstance && myObj .SomeBoolProperty)
        // Do Something
}
```

R# comprehends the assertion and will stop warning you. Also, it isn't such a bad practice to liberally insert these debugging assertions. Anytime you are receiving a reference type as an argument of a `public` method, I would assert that the value is not null, or in some cases throw an exception specifically for receiving a null parameter instead of waiting for the code to fail further down. It gets worse when that null is passed into other methods making it really difficult to know where and when the code will fail.